# Nginx rewrite website url and jump to another

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i have a url m.baobao18.com on tomcat server,and another url m2.baobao18.com on IIS,when people visit m.baobao18.com/ad/zhanyeweb ,i want to jump to m2.baobao18.com/ad/zhanyeweb,how should i config this in nginx,please help me ,there is no files in m.baobao18/ad/zhanyeweb

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation for [Nginix rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Something like this will do:

```
location /ad/zhanyeweb {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://m2.baobao18.com$1 permanent;
}
```

You could also prosy the requests.